# Sunburst Chart from R in Plotly not showing all values in outermost ring

Tags: r, graph, charts, graphics, plotly

I'm trying to take cell spatial data and make a sunburst chart out of the slide data. Here's the basic format of the dataframe I'm using for it.

```
structure(list(slide = c("LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
                               "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095"
), stroma_bins = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
                             5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
                             8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("0-10% Stroma", 
                                                                            "10-20% Stroma", "20-30% Stroma", "30-40% Stroma", "40-50% Stroma", 
                                                                            "50-60% Stroma", "60-70% Stroma", "70-80% Stroma", "80-90% Stroma", 
                                                                            "90-100% Stroma"), class = "factor"), cd8_percent_bins = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("0-2% CD8+ Cells", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2-4% CD8+ Cells", "4-6% CD8+ Cells", "6-8% CD8+ Cells", "8-10% CD8+ Cells", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "10-15% CD8+ Cells", "15-20% CD8+ Cells", ">20% CD8+ Cells"), class = "factor"), 
Freq = c(8L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 15L, 
         4L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 
         4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 17L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 51L, 18L, 
         24L, 24L, 17L, 32L, 21L, 11L)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                            "data.frame"))
```

I'm using Plotly in R, but for some reason it's only displaying the outermost layer of the Sunburst chart for one region.

[image: Faulty Sunburst Plot]

Here's the code I have for it so far.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
labels = df2$labels,
parents = df2$parents,
values = df2$values,
type = 'sunburst',
branchvalues = 'total')

fig
```

Comment: The data you provided doesn't match the data in the graph you've shown issues with. However, I was able to see one problem. You summarised the parent totals, but even though there are only 3 in your example data, I can see that one of the totals is incorrect. For `10-20 Stroma`, the value is 6, but the total of the children is 5 (its children will not plot). This could be due to an incomplete dataset. However, with the issues you said you're having, it fits. If you provide all of the data, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: For some reason Stack Overflow had some trouble the dataframe formatting and kept reading it is improperly formatted code. I just uploaded the ```dput``` output of the dataframe to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you did to aggregate your data to create the data set in your plot isn't in your question. However, I see that you have 3 levels, and you didn't use the argument `ids`. You don't have unique *children*, for Plotly to interpret, either.

Starting with the data from the `dput` output.

For the root or top-level

All of the data in `slide` is the same, but I wrote it this way to make it more dynamic. This returns one row because there is one unique value in the highest level.

```
d1 <- df2 %>% group_by(slide) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  mutate(ids = slide, parents = "") %>%
  rename(labels = slide) %>% 
  select(ids, parents, labels, values) # all frame same order
# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#   ids   labels values parents
#   <chr> <chr>   <int> <chr>  
# 1 LU095 LU095     435 ""
```

The next level, mid-level or first-child level

I'll take the same exact approach, but instead of leading with `slide`, I'll lead with `stroma_bins`. Additionally, the `ids` will contain the parent and current level.

```
d2 <- df2 %>% group_by(stroma_bins) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  mutate(ids = paste0(stroma_bins, " - ", unique(df2$slide)),
         parents = unique(df2$slide)) %>% 
  rename(labels = stroma_bins) %>% 
  select(ids, parents, labels, values)
# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#    ids                    parents labels         values
#    <chr>                  <chr>   <fct>           <int>
#  1 0-10% Stroma - LU095   LU095   0-10% Stroma        8
#  2 10-20% Stroma - LU095  LU095   10-20% Stroma       6
#  3 20-30% Stroma - LU095  LU095   20-30% Stroma       8
#  4 30-40% Stroma - LU095  LU095   30-40% Stroma       9
#  5 40-50% Stroma - LU095  LU095   40-50% Stroma      25
#  6 50-60% Stroma - LU095  LU095   50-60% Stroma      24
#  7 60-70% Stroma - LU095  LU095   60-70% Stroma      36
#  8 70-80% Stroma - LU095  LU095   70-80% Stroma      53
#  9 80-90% Stroma - LU095  LU095   80-90% Stroma      68
# 10 90-100% Stroma - LU095 LU095   90-100% Stroma    198
```

The next level has two parents, therefore *both* parents will be included. It follows the same premise as the last two, but in the `parents` column, we need to combine the parents. (I only included a sample of what this frame looks like.)

```
d3 <- df2 %>% 
  rename(labels = cd8_percent_bins,
         values = Freq) %>% 
  mutate(ids = paste0(labels, " - ", stroma_bins),
         parents = paste0(stroma_bins, " - ", unique(df2$slide))) %>% 
  select(ids, parents, labels, values)
#                                    ids                parents            labels values
#  1:     0-2% CD8+ Cells - 0-10% Stroma   0-10% Stroma - LU095   0-2% CD8+ Cells      8
#  2:    0-2% CD8+ Cells - 10-20% Stroma  10-20% Stroma - LU095   0-2% CD8+ Cells      5
#  3:    4-6% CD8+ Cells - 10-20% Stroma  10-20% Stroma - LU095   4-6% CD8+ Cells      1
#  4:    0-2% CD8+ Cells - 20-30% Stroma  20-30% Stroma - LU095   0-2% CD8+ Cells      7
#  5:    2-4% CD8+ Cells - 20-30% Stroma  20-30% Stroma - LU095   2-4% CD8+ Cells      1
#  6:    0-2% CD8+ Cells - 30-40% Stroma  30-40% Stroma - LU095   0-2% CD8+ Cells      7
#  7:    2-4% CD8+ Cells - 30-40% Stroma  30-40% Stroma - LU095   2-4% CD8+ Cells      2
#  8:    0-2% CD8+ Cells - 40-50% Stroma  40-50% Stroma - LU095   0-2% CD8+ Cells     15
#  9:    2-4% CD8+ Cells - 40-50% Stroma  40-50% Stroma - LU095   2-4% CD8+ Cells      4
# 10:    4-6% CD8+ Cells - 40-50% Stroma  40-50% Stroma - LU095   4-6% CD8+ Cells      4
```

Next, combine these three data frames into one data frame.

```
dd <- do.call(rbind, list(d1, d2, d3))
```

Now the data is ready.

```
plot_ly(dd, parents = ~parents, labels = ~labels, values = ~values,
        ids = ~ids, branchvalues = "total", type = "sunburst")
```

[image]